OpenLayers spherical area calculation is not matching with QGIS or PostGIS results
I have a GeoJSON feature in EPSG:4326 as follows
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "bd31",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -115.36519166399995,
                            51.09125115300003
                        ],
                        [
                            -115.36530041199995,
                            51.09154450600005
                        ],
                        [
                            -115.36565632699995,
                            51.09149226000005
                        ],
                        [
                            -115.36571987099995,
                            51.091442062000056
                        ],
                        [
                            -115.36525512899999,
                            51.09120913300006
                        ],
                        [
                            -115.36520446199995,
                            51.09124927800008
                        ],
                        [
                            -115.36519166399995,
                            51.09125115300003
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                
            }
        }
    ]
   
}

When I try to calculate areas using various things , here are the results

Using getArea from ol

import { getArea} from 'ol/sphere.js';
console.log(`spherical area - ${getArea(samplevectorSource.getFeatures()[0].getGeometry(),{"projection": map.getView().getProjection(), "type": 'geodesic'})}`)

Results --> 709.1299170830032


Using different radius of earth


console.log(`spherical area with different radius - ${getArea(samplevectorSource.getFeatures()[0].getGeometry(),{"projection": map.getView().getProjection(),"radius": 6371000})}`)

Results -->709.1279581031441


Using turf.js

const geojson = geometry.getCoordinates();
const polygon = turf.polygon(geojson);

const turfArea = turf.area(polygon); // Turf uses WGS84 ellipsoid
console.log("Turf.js Area:", turfArea);

Results -->709.1299172355682


geolib.js library

var geolib_area = geolib.getAreaOfPolygon(polygon.geometry.coordinates[0]
);

console.log(`geolib area xy - ${geolib_area}`)

Results -->710.7176243234481


QGIS

$area

Results -->711.7171691404656


PostGIS


SELECT 
    ST_Area(
        ST_SetSRID(
            ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
                '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-115.36519166399995,51.09125115300003],[-115.36530041199995,51.09154450600005],[-115.36565632699995,51.09149226000005],[-115.36571987099995,51.091442062000056],[-115.36525512899999,51.09120913300006],[-115.36520446199995,51.09124927800008],[-115.36519166399995,51.09125115300003]]]}'
            ), 4326
        )::geography
    ) AS area_m2;

Results -->711.7171631259844


Using geodesy

import LatLon from 'geodesy/latlon-nvector-spherical.js'

let geodesy_poly = []
polygon.geometry.coordinates[0].forEach(element => {
  geodesy_poly.push(new LatLon(element[1],element[0]))
});
  const geodesy_area = LatLon.areaOf(geodesy_poly);
console.log(`geodesy area - ${geodesy_area}`)

Results -->709.1200857356483

So Far QGIS is giving the most accurate result. How can I get similar results in OpenLayers?

PostGIS and QGIS are using https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/. It seems to be ported   on JavaScript. Try to find OpenLayers examples.

Two areas could be calculated: cartesian / 711,4 m² and ellipsoidal / 711,7 m². Regarding QGIS it uses EPSG:7030, which refers to the projection, which is based on the Clarke 1880 (RGS) ellipsoid. Try to conduct your calculations in the UTM associated with your region i.e. EPSG:32611. Also notice, that getArea() method in OL uses the 'EPSG:3857' and radius of 6371008.8 on the Clarke1866 Authalic Sphere by default.

See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/13572  It should be possible to extract the ol/geodesy.js module and use it in your own application.

@user30184, geographiclib worked :D Thank you

Geographiclib npm package worked for me to get the accurate , here is the code https://github.com/Rotten-Grapes-Pvt-Ltd/ol-measurement-geographiclib
